# Formatting a date from its parts

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'll try to as specific as possible. I have an export query and right now I have the date fields coming back like `YYYY-MM-DD` even if they're blank dates --

```
IsNull(RIGHT(Surg_Disch_Dt_Year,4)+'-'+SUBSTRING(Surg_Disch_Dt_Month,4,2)+'-'+LEFT(Surg_Disch_Dt_Day,2),'')+@Delimit+
```

This will get me closer to to my results

Here is one example

> 2008--15

I'm not completely sure why the substring portion isn't working. If I change the substring to something else like

```
IsNull(SUBSTRING(Surg_Disch_Dt_Year,1,4)+'-'+RIGHT(Surg_Disch_Dt_Month,2)+'-'+LEFT(Surg_Disch_Dt_Day,2),'')+@Delimit+
```

It completely changes my format to mm/dd/yyyy

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `case when rad_starT_date is null then '' else .... build yyyy-mm-dd stuff end case`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I get errors Invalid Column names and Incorrect Syntax.

Comment: For your next question please try to reduce your code to the actual problem...

Comment: Hi @user2516641, I just updated my answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You tagged this with SQL-Server-2012, that means you can use some handy functions like `TRY_CONVERT` and `FORMAT`

The trick with `REPLACE(STR(SomeValue,X),' ','0'` will lead to zero padded numbers with the length of "X". Numbers over this size will lead to "****". This parts are concatenated. The result is a number-string of 8 digits. If there is one `NULL`, the whole string will be `NULL`.

In anycase there is string typed result you can pass to `TRY_CONVERT`. This will try to convert to `DATE`. If it works it is a valid date, if not it returns `NULL`. And the final `ISNULL` will return a blank instead of a `NULL` for all cases, where the conversion failed...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Comment VARCHAR(100),Rad_Start_Date_Year INT,Rad_Start_Date_Month INT,Rad_Start_Date_Day INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('valid date',2016,7,5)
,('one missing',2016,NULL,5)
,('all missing',NULL,NULL,NULL)
,('invalid',2016,13,5);

SELECT ISNULL(FORMAT(TRY_CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE(STR(Rad_Start_Date_Year,4),' ','0')+REPLACE(STR(Rad_Start_Date_Month,2),' ','0')+REPLACE(STR(Rad_Start_Date_Day,2),' ','0')),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'')
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

### UPDATE: You might create a function for this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyDATEFROMPARTS(@y NVARCHAR(4),@m nvarchar(2),@d nvarchar(2))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(10)
BEGIN
    RETURN ISNULL(FORMAT(TRY_CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE(STR(@y,4),' ','0')+REPLACE(STR(@m,2),' ','0')+REPLACE(STR(@d,2),' ','0')),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'')
END
GO

DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Comment VARCHAR(100),Rad_Start_Date_Year INT,Rad_Start_Date_Month INT,Rad_Start_Date_Day INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('valid date',2016,7,5)
,('one missing',2016,NULL,5)
,('all missing',NULL,NULL,NULL)
,('invalid',2016,13,5);

SELECT tbl.Comment
      ,tbl.Rad_Start_Date_Year AS y
      ,tbl.Rad_Start_Date_Month AS m
      ,tbl.Rad_Start_Date_Day AS d  
      ,dbo.MyDATEFROMPARTS(tbl.Rad_Start_Date_Year,tbl.Rad_Start_Date_Month,tbl.Rad_Start_Date_Day) AS SureDate
FROM @tbl AS tbl
```

The result:

```
+-------------+------+------+------+------------+
| valid date  | 2016 | 7    | 5    | 2016-07-05 |
+-------------+------+------+------+------------+
| one missing | 2016 | NULL | 5    |            |
+-------------+------+------+------+------------+
| all missing | NULL | NULL | NULL |            |
+-------------+------+------+------+------------+
| invalid     | 2016 | 13   | 5    |            |
+-------------+------+------+------+------------+
```

Comment: I made some changes to my original question. I also tried something like this so it would on my side and got all blanks...

Comment: @user2516641, sorry, I do not understand you: Did you try something with `TRY_CONVERT` and `FORMAT`? The only change I see in your question is, that you reduced it by some lines. If you create the function I put with the `UPDATE-section`, you can easily pass in three parameters (y, m and d) and you will get the appropriate date as string or a blank. Right as you wanted it... So: What is wron? What is missing?

Comment: I updated the question a little better this time. After doing it for hours my brain was just done. The issue with what you suggested is that I have 15 tables that I will need do this to all with different names. When I tried to use your suggestion it wasn't grabbing all of the data. It was just grabbing random values so instead of my 122265 entries I was getting a couple thousand.

Comment: This actually did work. I just used SELECT ISNULL(FORMAT(TRY_CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE(STR(Rad_Start_Date_Year,4),' ','0')+REPLACE(STR(Rad_Start_Date_Month,2),' ','0')+REPLACE(STR(Rad_Start_Date_Day,2),' ','0')),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'') and when I did some testing and found out that Excel is being stupid and changing the date once exported. It works fine if I send it to a .txt file. Thanks for the help. The logic made sense but the outcome didn't.

Comment: Hi @user2516641, the point is: You must concatenate your date **first** and **after this use `TRY_CONVERT` to `DATE`**. If the concatenated string is a valid date, the conversion will work, otherwise it will return `NULL`. Btw: I've pushed you over the 15 rep points border. You are now allowed to vote on contributions and you are asked to use this right very often :-) Thx!